# Using MySQL FULLTEXT with PHP to search for words with less than 4 characters in a shared hosting

Tags: mysql, search, character, words, short

I have a simple PHP script that does a FULLTEXT search inside a MySQL database. I am hoping there is something I can do on the PHP side to resolve this as it seems there is not much I can do on the MySQL side.

I currently have this in a PHP class, and works 100% in my localhost but fails when uploading to my shared Godaddy hosting.

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $searchstring);
$searchwords = '';

foreach($pieces as $value) {
  $searchwords .= '+'.$value.' ';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE MATCH ( ItemName, ItemDescription ) AGAINST ('$searchwords' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

I have done a lot of research on a solution to this but haven't found any answers yet. All documentation and forums suggest to change the my.ini file ft_min_word_len=4 to for example ft_min_word_len=0 which works perfectly when testing on my localserver.

Since I need to upload my project to a godaddy shared hosting account I am unable to change the my.ini configuration file so I need a work around this error.

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

Search for 'iphone 5 LCD' the database will return all the results that have 'iphone' so it will show all 'iphone 4 home button' 'iphone 3 back' because from the original search query it skips the '5' and the 'lcd' for being less than 4 charcters. In my local copy since ft_min_word_len is set to ft_min_word_len=0 'iphone 5 lcd' only returns the items that I actually need! It works just perfect! I have attempted to fill short words like '5' with '5...' or '5___' or 'LCD_' or 'LCD*' or '5*' but it does not work. I read a solution that suggested 'padding' the short words but they didn't explain what characters to use.

Comment: Just switch to a hosting you find useful.

Comment: I think you can create your own my.cnf and put it in home directory, if your hosting allows it.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't a LIKE clause work.

Cut your search words to the desired length in php, then query WHERE (columnA LIKE '$searchword%' OR columnB LIKE '$seachword%')

or simply use php strlen to remove the words shorter than desired.